# How to use a type bounded parameter interface using generics

Tags: java

I have the class Test, which has an instance variable animalWithProps of type T (this variable should be of a type that implements AnimalProperty). However, when I try this with a class that implements this interface (Dog), I get an error for invalid types: `Dog cannot be converted to T`

```
interface AnimalProperty {
    String sound();
}

class Dog implements AnimalProperty {
    public String sound() {
        return "bark";
    }
}

class Test<T extends AnimalProperty> {
    T animalWithProp;

    public Test() {
        this.animalWithProp = new Dog();
        System.out.println(animalWithProp.sound());
    }
}
```

When I try doing `AnimalProperty prop = new Dog()`, it works. Why can't I have this type bounded parameter?

Comment: Because `T extends AnimalProperty` means a *specific* type of `AnimalProperty`, defined by the instantiator of `Test`, which might be `Cat` for all we know. If you want the field to hold any `AnimalProperty`, just declare it as `AnimalProperty`; no need for `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `T` is a *sibling* of `Dog` in the inheritance tree. For example, it could be `Cat`. Would it make sense to do `Cat c = new Dog()`? Of course it wouldn't. Here's what you want:

```
class Test {
    AnimalProperty animalWithProp;

    public Test() {
        this.animalWithProp = new Dog();
        System.out.println(animalWithProp.sound());
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to have animalWithProp as a typed object (T could be Dog, Cat, etc...), so I want to use generics. This wouldn't work

Comment: @Pablo I am afraid you can't do that. It wouldn't make sense to assign a dog object to some arbitrary reference type.